# C# shared class which name space does it belong?

Tags: c#, makefile

I have this design of a c# program where one file performs an encryption and another performs a decryption of a string, and I have two main methods. Since only one of the main functions will be executed at a given time, I don't think it would cause a problem (I understand c# programs are usually developed with Visual Studio, but I am using terminals for now).

Now, I have another class, which is used both when a string is encrypted and decrypted - the class has an algorithm that does the both. Since it does not include a main function, I thought I could use a namespace, but there would be two namespaces (one for the encryption main and the other for the decryption) and I did not know how to include the main-less class in both of the name spaces. I guess I could get away with creating an exact duplicate class, but I really wanted to avoid it.

My makefile currently looks like this and it complains that Enigma.cs lacks an entry point (main):

```
all:
    mcs Decode.cs
    mcs Encode.cs
    mcs Enigma.cs

clean:
    rm *.exe
```

Do you have any suggestions how this shared class can compile without adding a main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not compile Enigma separately, but rather include it in compilation of both Decode and Encode. That way you will still reuse the same class:

```
all:
    mcs Decode.cs Enigma.cs
    mcs Encode.cs Enigma.cs
```

Comment: Wow. Precisely. Thank you.